# Привязка региона и города при авторизации через VK, FB, OK

Tags: mysql, база-данных, авторизация

Есть существующая БД с таблицами Страны, Регионы, Города..
Все они естественно связаны друг с другом IDишниками.

Вопрос?

Как привязывать конкретную страну, регион и город при авторизации через VK или прочие соц сети?

Есть идея использовать LIKE% но не уверен что это правильный подход.

Может существует готовая сборка БД в которой ID конкретных стран регионов и городов совпадает с ID получаемыми при авторизации через VK, FB, OK итд..?

Comment: Угу... есть такая сборка - у этих самых *VK, FB, OK и т.д.*. Вот только кто тебе сказал, что они горят желанием ей поделиться?

Comment: Придётся тогда изобрести велосипед=) Хочу что бы при авторизации через соц сети город привязывался автоматом... Пока сделал через %LIKE%, если совпадений нет то заставляю пользователя после авторизации насильно город выбирать в всплывающем окне..